# Can't remove or stop a container

Tags: docker

The docker version is 0.10.0, the linux system is Centos6.5.
Three containers have been running in the system for 3 months in OpenStack. I put the nova-compute service in a container.

I found that nova-compute container didn't work recently.

I delete the *json.log* of the container when I found the log is 3GB,
but it still does not work.

I try to delete,stop,restart the container,restart the system,it's still the same.

```
dockerctl 6a82f22d2dad
lxc-attach:failed to get the init pid

docker rm -f 6a82f22d2dad
Error:
2015/08/11 08:51:32 Error:failed to remove one or more containers


docker stop 6a82f22d2dad
Error:failed to stop one or more containers
```

When running `docker ps`, the compute container works well.

Now I could not get other information because I can't connect the remote machine. Has anybody the same problem?

Comment: upgrade your docker version, docker 1.8 is available, I guess you will be able to stop

Comment: Thank you.I can't upgrade the docker version because it can't connect the Internet.I try to wipe out the directory of "/var/lib/docker" first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redhat has come right out and stated that they do not support Docker on CentOS 6.x systems.

If you can, I suggest you upgrade to CentOS 7 and the latest Docker version.

You can find more info about CentOS 6.x Docker support [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14365)

Comment: If you're satisfied, go ahead and mark this as the answer.